# assetic and filters

Tags: symfony, filter

I try to use the cssembed filter loading my stylesheets (because of the images referenced in the css)

In config.yml

```
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ cramifviewkitBundle ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    cssembed:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.4.5.jar
    yui_css:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    yui_js:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

I download cssembed-0.4.5.jar and located it in **src/my_bundle/Resources/java**

in the template I wrote :

```
{% stylesheets 
    '@myBundle/Resources/public/css/*'
    '@myBundle/Resources/public/JQMenu/css/*'
    filter='cssembed'
%}
```

Everything is fine for the first import, but for the second one, when I look with firebug, I have this :

```
<link type="text/css" href="/viewkit/web/app_dev.php/css/eb2d30c_part_1_jqueryMenus_1.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and when I open it, it is not css but html because there is an error :

```
<h1>Exception thrown when handling an exception    (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException: Warning: json_encode() [<a   href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in C:\wamp\www\viewkit\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter.php line 99)</h1>
<div class="block_exception clear_fix">
<h2><span>1/1</span> <abbr title="ErrorException">ErrorException</abbr>: Warning: json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in  C:\wamp\www\viewkit\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter.php line 99</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
 <ol class="traces list_exception">
 <li> in  C:\wamp\www\viewkit\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter.php line 99</li>
```

any idea where it could come from ?

Comment: You can get more info from your app/logs/dev.log

Comment: Is your CSS valid? Do you use some unusual characters in it?

Comment: it looks like underscore does not work... you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `cssembed-0.4.5.jar` in `app/Resources/java` directory as you specified in the configuration.

Comment: Just for clarification - in your question you said, you put it in your bundle's Resource directory.

Comment: I give the point not for this answer but for your comment... obviously everytime the error occurs there is a problem in the css, like the images are not found